# My own primefaces p:commanButton icon

Tags: jsf, primefaces, commandbutton

I cannot use my own icon for a primefaces p:commandButton. My code is:

```
    <p:commandButton value="Cancel" action="#{userBb.cancel()}" 
       icon="ui-icon-myCancel" />
```

css is:

```
.ui-icon-myCancel{
   background-image: url(images/cancel_16.png) !important;
}
```

Structure of folders is ordinary: `/resources/images/cancel_16.png`

As a result i get: [image]

When I try:

```
.ui-state-default .ui-icon .ui-icon-myCancel{
   background-image: url(images/cancel_16.png) !important;
}
```

I get:[image]

When I look at firebug report, there is section span

```
<span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-myCancel"></span>
```

there is:

```
.ui-state-default .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("/WarPort08_02b/javax.faces.resource/images/ui-icons_38667f_256x240.png.xhtml?ln=primefaces-aristo");
```

I have looked at this [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959654/need-help-to-display-an-icon-image-in-a-command-button), and others but found no answer.

When I try p:commandLink with h:graphicImage icon is visible, but it is an image as a button/link.

Comment: What about the third answer from the link you provided ? I left you a comment there also.

Comment: It doesn't work for me: <p:graphicImage value="images/cancel_16.png" /> . If I try: <p:commandLink ajax="false">  <p:graphicImage name="images/cancel_16.png" /> </p:commandLink> then I get a picture as a link that can be 'clicked', but I want a command button with icon AND title.

Comment: what's the size of your image ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Zbyszek, these are the steps I took to get the output below. Based on your comment, I'm assuming that's what you're after.

[image: commandButton with value and icon]

**Note**: My picture's name was `test.jpg` and it was in the following directory
`resources/images/test.jpg`.
Also the style rule you provided was placed in `resources/css/style.css`. The size of my image was 25 x 17 (but I doubt that's important. I'm just saying this in case you're thinking the icon is too small).

In `<h:head>` make sure you have (Maybe you forgot to add this and the styles weren't being applied ?)

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />
```

My <`p:commandButton>` (change as needed, it was just a quick mock up)

```
<p:commandButton value="Cancel" icon="ui-icon-myCancel" />
```

and your rule

```
.ui-icon-myCancel{
    background-image: url("#{resource['images/test.jpg']}") !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer. My fault was to give the wrong path to the image. I've coded it as this: url(images/cancel_16.png). But when I use JSF resource identifier in a way you did: url("#{resource['images/cancel_16.png']}") suddnely :) icon appeared. Also it appears when I code: url(../resources/images/cancel_16.png) or url(/MyAppName/resources/images/cancel_16.png). So it was all about proper reference to image, and I think that using resource identifier (which you show) is the best way.

Comment: @Zbyszek Yes, it was either the `h:outputStyleSheet` or the it wasn't locating the image. I ran into that problem awhile back. You didn't give me the wrong path, at least I don't think. I just added that note so you could see exactly what I was doing. Glad it worked out. You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

This simple url() version also works on Primefaces 6.1:
 `.ui-icon-myCancel{background-image: url(img/cancel.gif)!important;}`
(if you put the icon file to web/img folder and the css file is in web folder)
But it **rounds the corners** of icon therefore I use this solution:

```
.ui-icon-myCancel{background-image: url(img/cancel.gif)!important;  
                  border-radius: 0px!important;}
```